# Order of properties in RDF files

Tags: rdf

Is the order which have properties in an RDF/XML file significant? In other words, are the following two the same?

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/1">
  <ex:prop>1</ex:prop>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/2">
  <ex:prop>2</ex:prop>
</rdf:Description>
```

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/2">
  <ex:prop>2</ex:prop>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/1">
  <ex:prop>1</ex:prop>
</rdf:Description>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, RDF is mathematically defined as a set of triples so the order that those triples appear in whichever serialization of RDF you are using is entirely irrelevant.

That being said there are some serializations where the ordering would affect the triples produced e.g. a Turtle snippet using collection syntax:

```
<http://example.org/subject> <http://example.org/hasItems> ( "one" "two" "three" ) .
```

Would produce different triples from:

```
<http://example.org/subject> <http://example.org/hasItems> ( "two" "one" "three" ) .
```